Loading results of split vector tool into group using PyQGIS
I try to write a script to automatically merge some input layers (all of the same structure) of a GeoPackage into one, then split it by a specific attribute and save the output as GeoPackages to a defined directory. Afterwards, I want to import the layers into a group in the current project.
From the graphical model builder, I got this code:
from qgis.core import QgsProject
from qgis.core import QgsProcessing
from qgis.core import QgsProcessingAlgorithm
from qgis.core import QgsProcessingMultiStepFeedback
from qgis.core import QgsProcessingParameterMultipleLayers
from qgis.core import QgsProcessingParameterFolderDestination
import processing

class TEST(QgsProcessingAlgorithm):

    def initAlgorithm(self, config=None):
        self.addParameter(QgsProcessingParameterMultipleLayers('import_layers', 'Import Layers', layerType=QgsProcessing.TypeVectorPoint, defaultValue=None))
        self.addParameter(QgsProcessingParameterFolderDestination('output_folder', 'Output Folder', createByDefault=True, defaultValue='./Output'))

    def processAlgorithm(self, parameters, context, model_feedback):
        # Use a multi-step feedback, so that individual child algorithm progress reports are adjusted for the
        # overall progress through the model
        feedback = QgsProcessingMultiStepFeedback(3, model_feedback)
        results = {}
        outputs = {}

        # Merge vector layers
        alg_params = {
            'CRS': 'ProjectCrs',
            'LAYERS': parameters['import_layers'],
            'OUTPUT': QgsProcessing.TEMPORARY_OUTPUT
        }
        outputs['Mergevectorlayers'] = processing.run('native:mergevectorlayers', alg_params, context=context, feedback=feedback, is_child_algorithm=True)

        feedback.setCurrentStep(1)
        if feedback.isCanceled():
            return {}

        # Fieldcalculator
        alg_params = {
            'FIELD_LENGTH': 10,
            'FIELD_NAME': 'fid',
            'FIELD_PRECISION': 0,
            'FIELD_TYPE': 0,  # Dezimal (double)
            'FORMULA': '@id',
            'INPUT': outputs['Mergevectorlayers']['OUTPUT'],
            'OUTPUT': QgsProcessing.TEMPORARY_OUTPUT
        }
        outputs['Fieldcalculator'] = processing.run('native:fieldcalculator', alg_params, context=context, feedback=feedback, is_child_algorithm=True)

        feedback.setCurrentStep(2)
        if feedback.isCanceled():
            return {}

        # Split vector layer
        alg_params = {
            'FIELD': 'ATTRIBUTE',
            'FILE_TYPE': 0,  # gpkg
            'INPUT': outputs['Fieldcalculator']['OUTPUT'],
            'PREFIX_FIELD': False,
            'OUTPUT': parameters['output_folder']
        }
        outputs['Splitvectorlayer'] = processing.run('native:splitvectorlayer', alg_params, context=context, feedback=feedback, is_child_algorithm=True)
        results['output_folder'] = outputs['Splitvectorlayer']['OUTPUT']
        return results

    def name(self):
        return 'TEST'

    def displayName(self):
        return 'TEST'

    def group(self):
        return ''

    def groupId(self):
        return ''

    def createInstance(self):
        return TEST()

This works fine and the GeoPackages are stored correctly, but now I don't know how to load all of the layers into a common group in the current project. Any suggestions?

path = pathlib.Path(results['output_folder'])

group = QgsProject.instance().layerTreeRoot().addGroup("New Group")

for f in path.iterdir():
    if f.is_file() and f.suffix == ".gpkg":
        l = QgsVectorLayer(str(f), f.stem, "ogr")
        QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(l, False)
        group.addLayer(l)

